# Tree based chat program

Tags: chat

Often when I am discussing a topic, the conversation reaches a branch point, where there are two or more options that should be considered.

Is there any chat program/website that supports this?

Ideally, I am looking for a program that can show a diagram of the discussion, with optional titles on the boxes, and optional text on the connectors.

In case it is not clear, the users would have to categorize the sections and the connections.

Is there a program like this?

**Clarifications:**

Web based or runs on Windows/Linux. Also acceptable if I have to run the server myself (if its an open source project or the like I can also compile it if need be). Also, it should be a free program.

Comment: The XMPP client [OneTeam](http://oneteam.im/) has a thread feature (see slide 3), however, it seems that development stagnated.

Comment: Sounds like maillist.

Answer (score 3):

I use [Co-meeting](http://www.co-meeting.com/en/) everyday for structured business discussion.

- You can reply to anything, even inside a message.
- Webapp
- Runs fine in all browsers we tried, Windows/Mac/Linux
- Free for 20 chatrooms (you can reuse chatrooms)
- It does not have titles and connectors, though.

[image]